# .htaccess produces permission denied despite correct password

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I set up a .htaccess-file to protect a folder which is in the webroot. Let's call the folder /protected.
I placed the .htaccess and the .htusers file in this very folder (/protected). When I try to login into the folder using the correct login credentials I still get 403.
Here is the .htaccess file:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Service-Bereich"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile [FULL_PATH]/.htusers
Require valid-user
```

.htusers

```
mary:$afr1$oqJDM12K$iT9QWY4ETerG0LUtRzw8C.
```

(For security reasons: user data is not real! It is a mockup)
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please show us what `[FULL_PATH]` actually is.

Comment: [FULL_PATH] e.g. /var/www/html/mysite/protected_folder/.htusers

Comment: How did you create the entry for the password file, did you use the `htpasswd` command line utility that comes with Apache? https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/programs/htpasswd.html

Comment: Yes, I did it with the following command: htpasswd -c -B mary .htusers

Comment: I would not put the .htusers file in the directory containing web files.  Put it in a configuration directory.  It ensures no one can read the file via your web site.  Then set `LogLevel debug` and verify your error_log file for details...

Comment: Thank you. The issue is that I can neither access the directory below the web files nor the server logs which makes it quite quirky. In the end I thought about updating .htaccess to prohibit access to .htaccess and .htusers files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to get it working. I left out the AuthBasicProvider file directive and put a file into the directory. However, I would still be interested in getting it to work without placing a file into the directory. :)
Thank you for all who tried to help me solving the issue.